# Matplotlib clean all the text along the axis but leave the frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I want to remove all the text and ticks around the x/y axis in matplotlib.

But keep the frames and all the text within the figure e.g. legend etc.

The final result should look like a box contains an image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```